# Postgresql: How to access data of a transaction with another connection

Tags: postgresql

Goodmorning,

I use Postgresql for my database engine and some operations use transactions to be sure that everything goes fine. 
Sometimes I need to test some specific datas at "that poin" of my application but these operations often make al lot changes in the database and it's not easy to reproduce "all the changes made inside the transaction" with another connection (like using a PgAdmin query tool) outside the transaction to test the single aspect that i need.

One way to test the specific data, is to load the data into a variable, and then debug-it, but i was searching for a more "wide solution".

So that's the question: Is there a way to access the data of a specific connection (which is in transaction) with another connection/query_tool?

Thanks, 
Attilio

Comment: Not possible, Postgres does not not allow dirty reads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In postgresql (actually) there's no way to do it, full stop.